# How to deal with QGIS Time Manager error: no attribute 'animationFrameCounter'?

Tags: qgis, timemanager

I am using QGIS 2.6 and using the time manager I get the error shown in the attached image.

Does anyone know what the problem is and could offer a solution?

![image: error]

Answer (score 1):

It's a [known issue](https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager/issues/64) which is currently being worked on.

I think we'll soon release an update.